# Select all the column values with CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql, select, case

What I want to achieve is really simple. I have a **Select** statement where there is a parameter `@age`connected to a DropDownList. The `@age` parameter is used for the AGE column.

Now this DropDownList has a default value **ALL**, that when selected has to display any value in AGE column. Here is my logic:

```
SELECT * FROM tableaGE
where ([AGE] = CASE WHEN @Age = 'ALL' THEN ??? ELSE @Age END)
```

I cannot find documentation on the Internet on this topic. What shall I put instead of the **???**. I tried with ***** but it gives syntax error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really simple, just place the name of the field instead of **???**

```
where ([AGE] = CASE WHEN @Age = 'ALL' THEN [AGE] ELSE @Age END)
```